# Conditional dependson for multiple stage YAML

Tags: azure-devops, azure-pipelines, azure-pipelines-yaml

I have a YAML pipeline which contains some template files.

Within my pipeline, there are 4 stages that run in parallel to apply DSC.  I then have a destroy task which i would like to run, only when all 4 tasks have ran successfully.  When i try to add a depends on with a list:

```
dependsOn: 
   - Stage_A
   - Stage_B
   - Stage_C
   - Stage_D
```

The error I get is:

`The 'dependsOn' parameter is not a valid String.`

My template YAML looks like:

```
...

stages:

   ...
 
  - template: Apply-DSC.yml
    parameters:
      azureSub: '[sub]'
      AutoAccountResourceGroup: 'rg'
      AutoAccountName: 'aa'
      environment: 'b1'
      stageDependsOn: 'b1_apply'
  - template: Destroy-Pipeline.yml
    parameters:
      azureSub: '[sub]'
      terraformStorageAccountResourceGroup: 'rg'
      terraformStorageAccountName: '[]'
      terraformStorageContainerName: '[]'
      terraformStorageRemoteStateKey: '[].tfstate'
      environment: 'b1'
      terraformEnvironmentFileName: 'B01'
      dependsOn: 'Stage_A'
```

I have 4 stages within my `Apply-DSC.yml`

```
Stage_A
Stage_B
Stage_C
Stage_D
```

Question is, is this possible for my destroy stage to await a successful deployment of Stages A-D when using these stage templates?

Thanks.

Edit: Adding Destroy-Pipeline.yml

```
# Run & upload Terraform plan
parameters:
  - name: azureSub
    type: string
  - name: terraformStorageAccountResourceGroup
    type: string
  - name: terraformStorageAccountName
    type: string
  - name: terraformStorageContainerName
    type: string
  - name: terraformStorageRemoteStateKey
    type: string
  - name: environment
    type: string
  - name: terraformEnvironmentFileName
    type: string
  - name: dependsOn
    type: string

stages:
  - stage: Destroy_${{ parameters.environment }}
    dependsOn: ${{ parameters.dependsOn }}
    jobs:
    - deployment: '${{ parameters.environment }}_Destroy'
      displayName: '${{ parameters.environment }} Destroy'
      environment: '${{ parameters.environment }} destroy'      
      pool: 
        vmImage: windows-latest
      strategy:
        runOnce:
          deploy:
            steps:
            - download: current
              artifact: 'drop'
              name: 'Download_Terraform_code'
              displayName: 'Download Terraform code'            
            - task: ms-devlabs.custom-terraform-tasks.custom-terraform-installer-task.TerraformInstaller@0
              inputs:
                terraformVersion: '$(TerraformVersion)'
              displayName: 'Install Terraform'
            - task: TerraformCLI@0
              inputs:
                command: 'init'
                workingDirectory: '$(Pipeline.Workspace)/Drop'
                backendType: 'azurerm'
                backendServiceArm: '${{ parameters.azureSub }}'
                backendAzureRmResourceGroupName: '${{ parameters.terraformStorageAccountResourceGroup }}'
                backendAzureRmStorageAccountName: '${{ parameters.terraformStorageAccountName }}'
                backendAzureRmContainerName: '${{ parameters.terraformStorageContainerName }}'
                backendAzureRmKey: '${{ parameters.terraformStorageRemoteStateKey }}'
                allowTelemetryCollection: false
              displayName: 'Terraform Init'
            - task: PowerShell@2
              inputs:
                targetType: 'inline'
                script: |
                  terraform workspace select $(WorkspaceEnvironment)
                workingDirectory: '$(Pipeline.Workspace)/Drop'
              displayName: 'Select Workspace' 
            - task: TerraformCLI@0
              inputs:
                command: 'plan'
                environmentServiceName: '${{ parameters.azureSub }}'
                commandOptions: '-destroy -var-file="./environments/${{ parameters.terraformEnvironmentFileName }}.tfvars" -input=false'
                allowTelemetryCollection: false
                workingDirectory: '$(Pipeline.Workspace)/Drop'            
              displayName: 'Plan Destroy'
            - task: TerraformCLI@0
              inputs:
                command: 'destroy'
                workingDirectory: '$(Pipeline.Workspace)/Drop'
                environmentServiceName: '${{ parameters.azureSub }}'
                commandOptions: '-var-file="./environments/${{ parameters.terraformEnvironmentFileName }}.tfvars" -input=false '
                allowTelemetryCollection: false
              displayName: 'Run Destroy'
```

Comment: Posting the yml from the Destroy-Pipeline.yml may help get you an answer. Based on the error I think the dependsOn Parameter is set as a string and as such it expects a single string whereas you are passing it 4 strings (hence the error). If you search for yml parameter data types there is types such as object and stageList which should let you pass more than parameter value

Comment: Not sure if this is a mistake just here, but you should have space between dash and stage name like this.`- Stage_A`

Comment: @KrzysztofMadej apologies, that is just an editing problem when sanitizing.

Comment: @DavidCox88 thanks, i have now changed this to an object.  I did struggle finding any proper documentation and usage examples for this.  Thanks again.

Answer (score 2):

I changed the type from `string` to `object`

```
parameters:
  - name: dependsOn
    type: object
    default: []
```

Then within my template block i added the object like:

```
 - template: Destroy-Pipeline.yml
    parameters:
      ...
      dependsOn: ['Stage_A', 'Stage_B' ...]
```